# What can possibly go wrong with my site with my super simple HTML minification regex?

Tags: html, minify

The current HTML pages being rendered have a lot of whitespace. Minifying the HTML before sending it saves me about 25% in file size. I minify the text using these regexs (in Python):

```
def minify_html(text):
    text = re.sub(r'>\s+<', '><', text).strip()
    return re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)
```

I do not support `<pre>` and `<code>` tags on my site, but what would happened if I did via Markdown? My CSS is formatted accordingly (for inline lists for example). I only have very simple inline javascript such as Google Analytics or calling functions in an external file. This regex doesn't seem to slow down page renderings unlike other HTML minification libraries.

What issues could I come across?

Answer (score 2):

Also,

```
This is <em>an</em> <strong>example</strong>
```

Is very different from

```
This is <em>an</em><strong>example</strong>
```

But your regexp will convert the former to the latter.

Comment: yeah, i bypass that by writing `<em>an </em>` or something similar

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [this HTML/HTML5 compressor I wrote](https://gist.github.com/1729144) in production. Feel free to adapt it to your own needs.

Also: If you don't pass `conservative=True`, it'll be fairly radical in its compression.

Comment: nice. how is it with `<pre>` and `<code>` support? and do you find that is slows down rendering?

Comment: I can say the site it's being run on is extremely fast. `<pre>` and `<code>` aren't in use on that site, so it will probably mangle them terribly. It isn't very hard to circumvent this by finding them first and replacing them with placeholders, then replacing the placeholders back with the verbatim HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your page, but what could go wrong:

- PRE tag contents formatting
- JavaScript strings (this doesn't seem to be your
  concern, though)